# DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3 Not Compiling after NUGET Updates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget

The .NET Core project compiled fine new. Once you update your NUGET packages it fails with messages listed below.

This was happening before and after the install of the new tools.
Updated today: DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3

Errors:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error       3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.

Error       2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.

Error       1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`

Error       Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. I also removed the global.json version specification as I was told it just uses the latest which saves me some time, should I not be doing that?

I can not understand how this was not tested. I created a brand new clean web application using .NET Core template in VS2015. I updated NUGET, even tried including pre-releases. Now the whole thing fails.

Thoughts and questions:

1. Can anyone tell us how to create a simple .NET CORE WEB project config without all the bloat that will be hosted simply on a Windows Server? This is what most people will be doing. It would be nice to have a simple project.config and not as many dependencies when publishing to IIS. Every update you have to dig in and tweak your project config, this needs to stop right?
2. Why is the 'runtimes' section in the project config not included in the default template?
3. Seems strange to me that your project blows up every update.

Comment: What is your `.net core sdk` version? Also, update your question with your `project.json`. I've created a simple [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular) that may help you. It's for 1.0.0, but the process is the same for this new version.

Comment: Did you install the sdk/untime too? What inside `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` respectively folder?

Comment: @Tseng Nothing in x86 folder. Folder 1.0.1 in the C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App.

Comment: @Fabricio Koch Thank you I will go through your tutorial soon as VS 2017 is released as final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non-issue as they changed how all this works in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when upgrade Microsoft.NETCore.App from version 1.0.1 to version 1.1.0. Please add **"type":"platform"** option in Dependencies node in project.json.

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "platform"
 }
},
```

And we often use Web.config file to configure handler information when deploy to IIS. The project.json file used to manage the project dependencies. So if there has any dependencies changed in your project, you just need to upgrade your project.json file. The Web.config file need not to be changed.

About why the "runtimes" section not include in default project template issue, this is because different users need different runtimes. Every users could add this sections into project.json file based on the project's requirement.

Comment: I guess my question is why would a new .NET Core web application break (VS2017) after updating NUGET packages? Very confusing. The fact that the project.json is gone is fine but it must break a lot of existing applications.

Comment: First, you need to check what changed in that Updates packages. For example, if one of the updated package changes its target framework, but your .NET Core web application's framework is not changed. It will lead to the compile error. So when updating NuGet packages, please check what changed in the new version and make sure it is support your current project framework.

Comment: I will dig in when I have time. Had to drop .NET Core after it caused so much trouble. Will revisit soon. I will dig into all of your suggestions when I have some free time and try and get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the runtimes to your project.json file just as the error message indicated. For example:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": { }
  }
```

Usually, you don't need to specify the runtimes option. But it is needed for Self-contained deployments (SCD). Refer to [runTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#runtimes) and [Self-contained deployments (SCD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd) for more information.

Comment: I guess my question is why would a new .NET Core web application break (VS2017) after updating NUGET packages? Very confusing. The fact that the project.json is gone is fine but it must break a lot of existing applications.